# Three.js motion detection with web cam?

Tags: three.js

there are cool examples on internet that by useing threejs we can motion detect with a web cam,my question is can we dectect depth(Far and near) using threejs + webcam?

Answer (score 1):

I think the downvotes are because this isn't a three.js question. The question you want to ask is *how to get depth data with a webcam*. If you Google that you will find what you are looking for. Three.js in this case would be a way to visualize the data, not a way to generate it.